# $f\circ f\circ f(x)=x^9$ then $f$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

The full statement is:

If $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function and $f\circ f\circ f(x)=x^9$ then $f$ is increasing.

$(1)$ I was thinking about suppose that $f$ is decreasing (or constant) and then it is easy to get a contradiction.

After that I would like to state that

"*If $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continous and not increasing then there is an interval where $f$ is decreasing or constant.*"

and then I can use $(1)$ and get the result. But I still can't prove if the statement is true.

Any hint or any other solution?

Comment: $f$ is injective. A continuous injective function is either increasing or decreasing (*I am not sure to have understood if this was what you were asking for though*)

Comment: @charMD: That helps a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \mapsto x^9$ is one-to-one and onto, the function $f$ itself must also be one-to-one and onto. Together with continuity this means that $f$ is strictly monotone, so it must be strictly increasing.

As remarked in comments to some other answers, general continuous functions may fail to be monotone on any interval.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your statement is true.

Let $a,b$ be points, $b>a$ so that $f(b) \leq f(a)$. Let $c$ be the $x$ value where $f$ attains its maximum on the interval $[a,b]$. Clearly $c \neq b$ (or at least we can take $c \neq b$), and hence for some $\epsilon> 0$, $f$ will be decreasing or constant on the interval: $(c, c + \epsilon)$.

Comment: Is this true? The Weierstrass function is not increasing or decreasing on any interval.